# ¿Cómo puedo transformar una lista de usuarios para que sea gráficamente atractiva?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Necesito poder transformar algún objeto que pueda almacenar varia información como en mi caso, un jList y poder mostrarlo de una manera más estética. 
¿Cuál podría ser la manera más adecuada de hacer esto?

**Este es el código del jList que estoy usando**

```
private void resultados(){
        BaseDatos BD=new BaseDatos();
        BD.editarDatos();
        DefaultListModel modelo = new DefaultListModel();
        for(File path:BD.getPaths()) {      
            System.out.println(path);
            String archivo=path.toString().replace("data\\","");
            archivo=archivo.replace(".txt","");
            modelo.addElement(archivo);
         }
        usuarios.setModel(modelo);
    }
```

**Quiero que luzca de esta manera:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]